# Ошибка Fatal error: Call to undefined function Core\Controllers\Page::ActionHome()

Tags: php

Ругается на строчку с return.Я понимаю что ошибка в том что не может найти функцию, но даже при использовании include_once, ошибка остается

```
    public static function Go($routesList = [], $path)
    {
        foreach ($routesList as $route){
          if (
              $route->path == $path
          ){
              $run = "Core\Controllers\\".$route->controller.'::Action'. $route->action;
              return $run();
          }
        }

    }
```

Это файл index.php

```html
<?php
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);

spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    $path = '';
    $fixLocalhost = $class;
    $fixLocalhost = str_replace('\\', '/',$class);
    require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/'.$fixLocalhost.'.php' );
});

$routes = require  './config/routes.php';
$track  = \Core\Route::Go($routes, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Код класса

```html
<?php

namespace Core\Controllers;

class Page extends \Core\Controller
{
   public static function ActionHome(){
        self::view('home',[
            'tittle' => 'Главная',
        ]);
   }
    public static function ActionContacts(){
        self::view('contact',[
            'tittle' => 'Контакты',
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: и при чем тут индекс, если смотреть надо на класс?

Comment: добавила код класса в вопрос

Comment: попробуйте заэкранировать нормально слэши в имени класса, а не тут два, а тут один

Comment: либо вообще переписать в виде `$class::$mehod()` или `call_user_func([$class, $method])`

Comment: если оставить без указания пути  "$run = $route->controller.'::Action'. $route->action;" та же самая ошибка Fatal error: Call to undefined function Page::ActionHome()

Comment: я не предлагал вам такого варианта